# Why am I getting the error Maximum call stack size exceeded in Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've eliminated all the ways of 'next' being called twice to prevent loops. Everything seems to work except what's going on inside the `if (authenticated)` block. The goal is to keep the user stuck at the RegisterFlow page until they've verified & provided a display name. Where am I going wrong?

Error: `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Code:

```
const authPages = ["LoginPage", "Register", "ForgotPass"];
const publicPages = ["PrivacyPolicy", "Terms"];

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  console.log("name", to.name);
  if (!store.state.auth.ready) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch("auth/authenticate");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("@router err: ", err);
    }
  }

  const authenticated = store.state.auth.authenticationStatus;
  const verified = store.state.auth.verificationStatus;
  let displayName = null;
  if (store.state.auth.user && store.state.auth.user.displayName) {
    displayName = store.state.auth.user.displayName;
  }

  if (publicPages.includes(to.name) || to.name == "Landing") {
    next();
  } else if (authenticated) {
    if (verified && displayName) {
      if (authPages.includes(to.name) || to.name == "RegisterFlow") {
        next("/");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next({ name: "RegisterFlow" });
    }
  } else if (!authenticated) {
    if (authPages.includes(to.name)) {
      next();
    } else if (to.name == "RegisterFlow") {
      next({ name: "LoginPage" });
    } else {
      next({ name: "LoginPage" });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block:

```
    if (verified && displayName) {
      if (authPages.includes(to.name) || to.name == "RegisterFlow") {
        next("/");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next({ name: "RegisterFlow" });
    }
```

When someone is not (verified && displayName) you will always trigger a next({name: "RegisteFlow"}) even if to.name == RegisterFlow. This causes the infinite loop. Something like:

```
    if (verified && displayName) {
      if (authPages.includes(to.name) || to.name == "RegisterFlow") {
        next("/");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      if (to.name == "RegisterFlow") { 
         next();
      } else { 
         next({ name: "RegisterFlow" });
      }
    }
```

will probably do the trick.